# Make use of all CPUs on SLURM

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, slurm

I would like to run a job on the cluster. There are a different number of CPUs on different nodes and I have no idea which nodes will be assigned to me. What are the proper options so that the job can create as many tasks as CPUs on all nodes?

```
#!/bin/bash -l

#SBATCH -p normal
#SBATCH -N 4
#SBATCH -t 96:00:00

srun -n 128 ./run
```

Comment: Best to consult all details about job-submission with your HPC-cluster Support Team. Did you try to ask them for providing a help with details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One dirty hack to achieve the objective is using the environment variables provided by the SLURM. For a sample sbatch file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --output=res.txt
#SBATCH --time=10:00
#SBATCH --nodes=2
echo $SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE
echo $SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES   
num_core=$SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE
num_node=$SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES
let proc_num=$num_core*$num_node
echo $proc_num
srun -n $proc_num ./run
```

Only the number of nodes are requested in the job script. `$SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE` will provide the number of cpus per node. You can use it along with other environment variables (eg: `$SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES`) to know the number of tasks possible. In the above script dynamic task calculation is done with the assumption that the nodes are homogenous (i.e `$SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE` will give only single number ).

For heterogeneous nodes, `$SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE` will give multiple values (eg: 2,3 if the nodes allocated has 2 and 3 cpus). In such scenario, `$SLURM_JOB_NODELIST` can be used to find out the number of cpus corresponding to the allocated nodes and with that you can calculate the required tasks.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a try.